# in gcloud console iam how can I add roles to groups?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, roles

I want to know how to add roles to groups. How is that done in the gcloud iam console? (https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin)

Answer (score 3):

There is no special action to take if you want to grant the roles through the cloud console, as indicated by the help text on the input field:

[image]

Simply write the group email, and select the roles you want to grant.

Note that the group must be a Google group or a G Suite group to work (Google needs to know who is a member of the group to grant the right permissions to the accounts).

The detailed steps are on [the IAM docs](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#access-control-via-console).

Comment: I noticed, when it comes groups, GCP does not "find" as you start typing. For groups, you have to put in the whole email address and then it works.